# Python Selenium - Find Element not working for a button

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Can anyone assist in clicking a button on a website using Selenium? On the main landing page, I want to click the "Confirm" button. I get an `no such element: Unable to locate element:` error. Please see my code below:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./driver/chromedriver")
  
driver.get("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/")
  
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
  
login_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button__BaseButton-sc-1qpsalo-0 clGTKJ")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `button__BaseButton-sc-1qpsalo-0` `clGTKJ` are **2** class name values. To use multiple class name values you can use `CSS_SELECTOR` or `XPATH` but not `CLASS_NAME` because this method receives **single** class name value.
2. `button__BaseButton-sc-1qpsalo-0 clGTKJ` class names appearing in 3 elements on that page. I guess you wanted to click a `confirm` button, if so another selector can be used, as following.
3. You should not use hardcoded sleeps like `time.sleep(10)`. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits should be used instead.

The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://www.xe.com/currencytables/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Amazing! works like a charm. In your screenshot would you know a way to export the table to csv? or is that a separate question? Appreciate the swift response though!

Comment: I'm always happy to help :) As about your second question - first this is absolutely different question, so you should ask about that separately. Also personally I'm not sure I know how to do that. At least until you will clarify what you want to do there. In case you mean doing that with Selenium - I think I will be able doing that, but if you want to use some scraping tool - this is not something I'm professional with...

Comment: Understood. Thank you again for the help, i am sure i will have more questions as i am motivated to learn this language! :)

Comment: Great! What language do you mean, python?

Comment: that is correct, i know basics right now where i can piece things together slowly. I have strong SQL skills though

Comment: OK, when you have new questions - don't hesitate to ask. I'm not 24/7 here and do not know all but in case I can help - will try doing that